# Android App crashes when Imgproc.Canny function is called

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I've been working on an app that detects changes in pupil size. However, at the moment I'm stuck on a section of code using the Canny function in the openCV library.

```
    private void runOpenCVCode() {
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(locations.get(0));
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            Mat mat = Mat.zeros(100,400, CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);
            //check mat
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bm);
            pic.setImageBitmap(bm);

            Mat gray = new Mat(mat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 4);

            Bitmap bmGray = Bitmap.createBitmap(gray.cols(), gray.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(gray, bmGray);
            pic.setImageBitmap(bmGray);

            Mat edges = gray;
            double thresh = Imgproc.threshold(gray, edges, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
            Imgproc.Canny(gray, edges, 80, 100);

            Bitmap bmEdges = Bitmap.createBitmap(edges.cols(), edges.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(edges, bmEdges);
            pic.setImageBitmap(bmEdges);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The code runs fine until it hits the canny function call. If it is commented out the rest runs without a problem. I'm assuming it is a native crash since the app crashes without any errors in the log and goes straight back to the initial activity. I've tried instantiating the matrices gray and edges various ways, and using different thresholds but nothing seems to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the log, if there is no log mostly because the log get cleared when a new activity is recreated !

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE how do I stop the log from clearing so I can get the log ?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50637228/1693327 but I am unable to comment to the post due to lack of reputation points so I will copy the answer below.

I believe the app is crashing when it hits the Canny detector because of the wrong type of OpenCV Manager installed on your device, be it version number or central processor instruction set. Checking the correct version should be straightforward. Just go to the OpenCV-android-sdk\apk directory and check for the 3 (x.y.z) numbers after OpenCV_

**Checking instruction set of Android devices for Windows**

To check the instruction set of your device, navigate to the adb (android debug bridge) directory commonly located at:

C:\Users\<'your username'>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
Run the command:

```
./adb.exe shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

After getting the correct instruction set, navigate back to the OpenCV-android-sdk\apk and locate the correct apk version and instruction set to be installed on your android device.

You can then transfer the apk to your device and install it. Another way I find useful is to navigate to the adb.exe directory and run the command:

```
./adb.exe install <path to OpenCV-android-sdk>/apk/OpenCV_x.y.z_Manager_x.yz_<platform instruction set>.apk
```

Apart from the steps above, make sure that you do not have any other environment variables that use other types of OpenCV Manager such as stating a different one in the Application.mk or build.gradle files.

After the steps above, your Canny detector should be able to run on your device without crashing.

Happy Developing :).